# Why do I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' along with /ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.js:8" in VS Code 1.77 with NodeJS versions <= 12?

Tags: visual-studio-code, loader, bootloader, unexpected-token

I've seen this error in several Stack Overflow posts, but none of them are quite like this, nor have they help.  Every time I try to run my program I see this:

```
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.js:8
`+r)),e.removeListener("error",er),e.destroy()}});var Rs=V((Vu,Cs)=>{"use strict";var xa=Object.create,pt=Object.defineProperty,ba=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor,Ss=Object.getOwnPropertyNames,va=Object.getPrototypeOf,Sa=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,Ea=(e,t)=>function(){return t||(0,e[Ss(e)[0]])((t={exports:{}}).exports,t),t.exports},Ta=(e,t)=>{for(var r in t)pt(e,r,{get:t[r],enumerable:!0})},Es=(e,t,r,n)=>{if(t&&typeof t=="object"||typeof t=="function")for(let s of Ss(t))!Sa.call(e,s)&&s!==r&&pt(e,s,{get:()=>t[s],enumerable:!(n=ba(t,s))||n.enumerable});return e},Ca=(e,t,r)=>(r=e!=null?xa(va(e)):{},Es(t||!e||!e.__esModule?pt(r,"default",{value:e,enumerable:!0}):r,e)),Ra=e=>Es(pt({},"__esModule",{value:!0}),e),Aa=Ea({"node_modules/request-light/lib/node/main.js"(e){(()=>{var t={46:(i,a)=>{"use strict";Object.defineProperty(a,"__esModule",{value:!0}),a.default=function(l,f,{signal:c}={}){return new

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:12)
    at loadPreloadModules (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:443:5)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:62:3)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:7:1
Process exited with code 1
```

It looks like it's in the extension that the problem is encountered.

`/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.js:8`

Tried several NodeJS versions. My current working version is 12.13.1.

Answer (score 3):

##### Cause

This is probably a case of [VS code crashes when debugging after update with Node <=12 #1624](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1624) (given that at least three (from my google search) similar issue tickets were raised in the VS Code GitHub repo recently, with two already closed as a duplicate of it: [VS Code debugger crashing on version 1.77.0 (Universal)
#178769](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178769), [Javascript Debug Terminal does not work with node version earlier than 14.15.1
#178759](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178759), [Unable to run code after update to VSCODE v1.77.0
#178998](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178998))

##### Solutions

This might be fixed now. Try updating to VS Code 1.77.1. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179288.

You have options:

- [That issue is now fixed in the nightly version of the `vscode-js-debug` extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1624#issuecomment-1492438222). Try [switching to it](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly).
- Wait a bit longer for the recovery build of the extension to be released.
- Rolling back your VS Code installation is also an option, since that will roll back the builtin version of the `js-debug` extension, but I don't really know why you'd do that over switching to the extension's nightly version.

---

For your reference, I found this info by googling "`github vscode issues "Unexpected token '.'" "ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.js:8"`"

Comment: I actually did a lot of googling on this and kept seeing different links that didn't help me, I was thrown off by including the error line with loader.js.  I did see a suggestion about using the nightly extension but didn't have faith that that was the issue.  Frankly I can't believe MS released something with that kind of bug, they should be ashamed.

Comment: @SaugusBull I'm confused. Are you saying this answer post did or didn't solve your problem?

Comment: Oh, it totally helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback VSCode to Feb 2023

This bug was introduced some time in March this year

1.75.1 seems to work for me

Comment: I went back to 1.73.1 and on one try it seemed to work, and then the next try the error returned.  Very frustrating.

Comment: @SaugusBull auto update turned on?

Comment: Yes, I had the auto-update turned on

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I had to race to turn auto update to off before it auto updated after install of 1.75.1.